# How to create Azure AI services multi-service account using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-ai

I am aware of Azure openai service can be created using [`azurerm_cognitive_account`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cognitive_account).

```
resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "openai_services" {
  for_each                      = { for openai in var.openai_services : openai.name => openai }
  name                          = each.value.name
  location                      = each.value.location
  resource_group_name           = each.value.resource_group_name
  kind                          = "OpenAI"
  sku_name                      = each.value.sku_name
  public_network_access_enabled = each.value.public_network_access_enabled
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  tags = merge(var.default_tags, each.value.tags)
}
```

However, I am unware if facility exist for [multi-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/multi-service-resource?tabs=windows&pivots=azportal) in Azure Terraform provider.

How to create Azure AI services multi-service account using Terraform?

Comment: Try replacing kind = "CognitiveServices"  for a multi-service account

Comment: Ah! ok got it so only `kind` changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to create an Azure AI services multi-service account using Terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

To achieve this configuration make sure you provide with necessary permissions to the **`contributor`** level.

The Only change that needs to take place here is kind = "CognitiveServices" This makes your Cognitive Services account act as multi service account.

The major changes among the two types of kinds are:

- **Multi-Service Account:** Provides access to multiple Azure Cognitive Services (e.g., Text Analytics, Computer Vision, Face API) under a single subscription using one set of keys and endpoint.
- **Self-Service (Single-Service) Account:** Dedicated to one specific Cognitive Service, requiring separate subscriptions and separate keys for each service.

**My terraform configuration:**

##### main.tf:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "example" {
  name                = var.cognitive_account_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  kind                = "CognitiveServices" # This is for multi-service account

  sku_name = "S0"

  tags = {
    environment = "production"
  }
}
```

##### variable.tf:

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group"
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The Azure Region in which all resources in this example should be created."
  type        = string
}

variable "cognitive_account_name" {
  description = "The name of the cognitive services account"
  type        = string
}
```

**terraform.tfvars:**

```
resource_group_name    = "vkCognitiveServicesRG"
location               = "East US"
cognitive_account_name = "vkCognitiveServiceAccount"
```

##### Output.tf:

```
output "cognitive_account_endpoint" {
  value = module.cognitive_account.endpoint
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]