# Error while creating Azure AI Multi Service Account using Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, terraform-provider-azure

I tried to create Azure AI Multi-Service (kind=CognitiveServices) account using terraform's `azurerm_cognitive_account` like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77407269/how-to-create-azure-ai-services-multi-service-account-using-terraform).

But it reports error:

```
Error: creating Account (Subscription: "xxx"
Resource Group Name: "yyy"
Account Name: "xxx-ais-msa"): unexpected status 400 with error: ResourceKindRequireAcceptTerms: 
This subscription cannot create CognitiveServices until you agree to Responsible AI terms for this resource. 
You can agree to Responsible AI terms by creating a resource through the Azure Portal then trying again. 
For more detail go to https://aka.ms/csrainotice

  with module.azureai_multiservice.azurerm_cognitive_account.azureai_multiservices["xxx-ais-msa"],
  on ../modules/LandingZone/AIKM/azureai_multiservice/main.tf line 13, in resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "azureai_multiservices":
  13: resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "azureai_multiservices" {

##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: Terraform Apply
```

- Do I need to create additional resources for `csrainotice`?
- If yes, how do I do this? Can't find such resource or argument reference on documentation?

Comment: The error message you've encountered indicates that your Azure subscription must agree to the Responsible AI terms for Cognitive Services before you can create the kind of resource you're trying to provision with Terraform.

Comment: @VinayB Do you mean the subscription owner need to digitally sign the Data Protection Addendum (DPA) docx like [here](https://aka.ms/DPA)? Or do you mean there is a flag to set this (can't find this though)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to creating Azure AI Multi Service  Account using Terraform and I was able to provison the requirement successfully.

The error message you're encountering indicates that before you can create a Cognitive Services resource with the specified kind (`CognitiveServices`), you must first agree to the Responsible AI terms for that resource type in your Azure subscription. This is a legal agreement that must be accepted in the Azure Portal before you can proceed with deployment via Terraform.

For reference of the [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77407269/how-to-create-azure-ai-services-multi-service-account-using-terraform/77409714#77409714) by me, In order to provision a cognitive service you should possess "**Cognitive Services Contributor**" Role.

Unfortunately, there's no Terraform resource or argument that can be used to accept these terms because it's a legal agreement that requires explicit consent through the Azure Portal. This is a manual step that cannot be automated through Terraform.

To provision the Coginative services follow the steps mentioned below.

- Log in to the Azure Portal.
- Navigate to the "Cognitive Services" creation page.
- Start the creation process for a Cognitive Services resource.
- During this process, you should be prompted to accept the Responsible AI terms.
- Accept the terms and complete the creation of the resource (this can be a minimal configuration just to get past the agreement process).

[image]

By clicking on the link you will be redirect to Application request form [page](https://customervoice.microsoft.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR7en2Ais5pxKtso_Pz4b1_xUOFA5Qk1UWDRBMjg0WFhPMkIzTzhKQ1dWNyQlQCN0PWcu) Which will redirect to a form which helps in accepting in terms and conditions from Microsoft which in general takes a day or two to get approval.

Once you get the approval check with the all the necessary role permission and start provisioning using terraform.

**My demo terraform configuration with relevent  Permission SP level :**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demovk-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "example" {
  name                  = "demovk-ais-msa"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  kind                  = "CognitiveServices"
  sku_name              = "S0"

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]